# Send message from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity, handler, message

I have an activity `(Activity_A)` that has a `handler` and is `receiving messages` from an external `library`. The problem is that `Activity_A` launches activity `Activity_B`. When `Activity_B` is launched, `Activity_A` `receives a message` on the `handler` that I want to "send" to `Activity_B`.

How to do that?

I cannot move the `handler` from `Activity_A` to `Activity_B` as some of the `messages` that receives have to be managed by `Activity_A.`

I would like to avoid using `global/static variables`.
Is it possible to somehow save in `Activity_A` a reference to `Activity_B` when I create the `intent`? How to send a `message` from `Activity_A` to `Activity_B` ?

An important point here is that, yes, I want to pass an object from one activity to another, but not in the moment I create the new activity (passing the object in a bundle). I want to do it asynchronously, whenever I receive a message from an external library.

Comment: You should consider a complete different approach. Your activity A might be killed completely when you start activity B. Instead of a handler that receives something, you might want to consider a broadcast receiver that handles/listens to specific intents (which are nearly the same as messages)?

Answer (score 9):

In `Activity_A`

```
String msg = "message";
Intent i = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
i.putExtra("keyMessage", msg);
startActivity(i);
```

In `Activity_B`

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String msg = extras.getString("keyMessage");
```

Hope it's help.

UPDATE:
I described the process of interaction of two Activities. But if message arrived from library, when `Activity_B` run - this method is not relevant. 
Try to move handler to some [Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html), which will work when you will need to. And from `Activity_A` and `Activity_B` you can periodically inquire service "came a new message?" using [Timer](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

Comment: I updated my answer, check it, please.

Answer (score 0):

Application can't work that way. If you want activity to make some job it must be visible to user.
You can consider Service to do background jobs (i.e. sensor handling), or make Activity B fragment - then actibity A will be still in foreground while it's fragment is visible to user.